# Vertical alignment of nodes in graphviz

Tags: graphviz, dot

I am trying to make a graph where {C1;C2} are aligned vertically. Same with {A;B;C} and {E1;E2;E3}

Here is my code so far:

```
digraph G{
    rankdir="LR";
    S -> C1 [label="150"];
    S -> C2 [label="130"];
    C1 -> A [label="70"];
    C1 -> B [label="80"];
    C2 -> B [label="60"];
    C2 -> C [label="70"];
    C -> B [label="10"];
    A -> E1 [label="70"];
    B -> E1 [label="80"];
    B -> D [label="70"];
    C -> E3 [label="60"];
    D -> E1 [label="40"];
    D -> E2 [label="0"];
    D -> E3 [label="30"];
    E1 -> t [label="190"];
    E2 -> t [label="0"];
    E3 -> t [label="90"];
}
```

Here is the result so far:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`{ rank = same; }` is your friend. I have added invisible edges between A, B and C to keep them tighter together, and reversed one of your connections in orde to keep A over B over C etc.

```
digraph G
{
    rankdir="LR";
    { rank = same; C1 C2 }
    { rank = same; A -> B -> C[ style = invis ] }
    { rank = same; E1 E2 E3 }
    S -> C1 [label="150"];
    S -> C2 [label="130"];
    C1 -> A [label="70"];
    C1 -> B [label="80"];
    C2 -> B [label="60"];
    C2 -> C [label="70"];
    B -> C [dir = back, label="10"];   // to keep B above C
    A -> E1 [label="70"];
    B -> E1 [label="80"];
    B -> D [label="70"];
    C -> E3 [label="60"];
    D -> E1 [label="40"];
    D -> E2 [label="0"];
    D -> E3 [label="30"];
    E1 -> t [label="190"];
    E2 -> t [label="0"];
    E3 -> t [label="90"]; 
}
```

yields

[image]